# Import Access database into SQL Express (Visual Studio)

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-express

I'm trying to understand how visual studio works with databases but cannot get it figured out.

I have a visual studio project with a built in(.mdf) database that is located in the APP_DATA folder.  I also have an access .accdb file elsewhere on my computer.  What I am trying to do is import it into the mdf database.

I know that mdf file in the APP_DATA corresponds to SQL Express.  However, I am completely confused because it looks like my computer has it's own seperate version of SQL Exprses because there is a separate folder located at

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA

with its own mdf/ldf files.  Furthermore, when I connect with Navicat, I can connect but see no databases.

How do I interface with the SQL Express instance that runs with my visual studio projects and import data that way?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the connection string? It is not too difficult to write a query that runs against an SQL Express or an Access connection that will update in one jump. MS Access : `SELECT * Into ANewTable FROM [ODBC;FILEDSN=Z:\Docs\Test.dsn;].table_1` Test.dsn could be a suitable ODBC connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Upsize to SQL Server option from inside of Access or download the Sql Server Migration Assistant for Access (http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/product-info/migration-tool.aspx#Access) tool.

The final option would be to open up the MDF in Sql Management Studio, and import the data through the TASKS->Import data tool.

Comment: I have tried the upsize tool and it says it has successfully migrated the file.....somewhere.  I migrated it to ./SQLEXPRESS with Windows Authentication.   However, Navicat still says there are no databases.  I am currently download SQL Management studio

Comment: Also would this make it 'portable'...that is would it be attached to the APP_DATA directory so if I was to move it to another computer, the database would stay intact?

Comment: when you get mgmt studio, you'll be able to connect to the EXISTING mdf file in your APP_DATA directory and perform queries against it.